# How to suppress error in pycharm community edition?

Tags: pycharm

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) solution to merge two dictionaries in python in pycharm Community Edition 4.5.4. But the following code is showing error, although when I run the code it works perfect:

```
feats = {**feats, **feature_detector(words)} # one big dictionary
```

How can I disable it in pycharm?

**EDIT**

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here is the options that I get after hitting alt+Enter:

[image]

Comment: Please attach a screenshot with error

Comment: Have a look at the edit, I've attached the screenshots

Comment: In the bottom-right, you have a face. (next to that lock). Click on it, and then select any `Syntax`. This will only highlight serious formatting problems. 

Or you could hit `Alt+Enter` and select `Ignore errors like this`. But I think this will have to be done each time you open PyCharm

Comment: I tried setting the slider to `None`, `Syntax` and `Exceptions`. Nothing happens. @SnuKies please have a look at the Edit, I don't get anything like `Ignore errors like this`

Comment: Hmm.. I do not know.
Usually, on the scrollbar, a line will appear for every exception (like yours). When I change from `Exceptions` to `Syntax`, those line would (the majority) disappear...

Comment: Updating PyCharm helped resolving the issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out that updating PyCharm may help resolve the issue. So I downloaded the latest version (`2016.2.3`). And then there was no error.